# Why do I sometimes see a file named something like ".nfs000000000048134c000001e7" when I run ls -a?

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm ssh'd into a server running some form of linux. Here's what `ls -al` returns:

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 ari csugrad 12088 Jan 20 20:33 .nfs000000000048134e000001e8`

It's an executable file, and executing it seems to print 8 bytes of nonsense (which is EXACTLY what the program I'm currently debugging is doing – coincidence?). Furthermore, `less`ing it reveals that its mostly in binary, but with a LOT of parts that correspond to actual strings (strings, as in half static data from my program and half strings that I don't recognize).

It almost looks like an object file? But why does it have an `nfs` prefix?

My only guess is that its a file that keeps track of all the data I send and receive in order to help out the file storage system that the server is hooked up to.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/234727/453007

Comment: It seems like the fact that executing it caused 8 bytes of nonsense to be printed wasn't a coincidence, there might've been instructions in there that came directly from my file. It still seems like a miracle that it executed cleanly, though? –– Thanks for that link, though! I suppose I didn't do a thorough enough google search.

Comment: "Oh, there's a mysterious executable, totally unexpected… Let's execute it then! What's the worst that could happen?"